# Active material slot

Tags: python, scripting

I have 200 material slots. I know how to iterate through them, but I cannot make them active.

```py
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    for m in o.material_slots:
        if "screen" in m.name:
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='MATERIAL', threshold=0.01)
```

But I cannot execute the last operator, as I cannot make them active material.

I have to just select similar materials by name and separate them as a new objects. Unfortunately, I cannot way of selecting textures by name, so I cannot execute `select_similar` and separate operators.

To be more precise, I have a *.obj* file. It contains 200 materials. I should separate it into 2 groups, group 1 is *wall*, and group 2 is *furniture*. I am able to iterate through material_slots and find certain materials which I need. **But** I cannot select them in edit mode. I have every material's name, I should select 20 or 30 of them and separate them into new objects.

Comment: Hello and welcome. your operator will throw an exception because you did not specify the context https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Comment: I have to just select similar materials by name and seperate them as a new object. Unfortunetly I cannot way of selecting textures by name, so I cannot execute select_similar and seperate operators. I have been stucked for a week.

Comment: Do you need the operator or is a `bpy.context.object.active_material_index = idx` good enough to make the material active? It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve. *Select Similar > Material* has no threshold, and it looks like it only works in *Edit* mode. A bit more context on what your goal is would help.

Comment: Ok, the threshold is shown in the Python console. But `bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar(type='MATERIAL', threshold=0.01)` selects all faces with the material that the active face in *Edit* mode has. So why do you need to loop through all material slots and look for a material with "screen" in the name?

Comment: sorry, it is my very first post in forums. To be more precise, I have a .obj file. It contains 200 hundred materials. I should seperate it 2 groups, group1 is wall, group2 is furnitures. I am able to iterate through material_slots and find certain materials which I need. BUT i cannot select them in edit mode. I have every materials name, I should select 20 or 30 of them and seperate into new group.

Comment: Don't worry. Welcome :) I think (and hope) what you're looking for is `bpy.ops.object.material_slot_select()` in addition to the `...active_material_index = idx` from the comment above. I'll post a complete script below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that checks the material slots of all mesh objects. If there is the word `screen` in the material's name then it selects the vertices of this material and checks the next material. After the check, the selection is separated into a new object if there were matches.

I think what you were actually looking for are lines 31 and 32:

```
31:         bpy.context.object.active_material_index = idx
32:         bpy.ops.object.material_slot_select()
```

but you also need to select the object to have the correct context (line 21) and do a few other safety checks.

The complete script looks like this:

```
import bpy

# save objects because the operation 'Separate Selection' creates new objects 
objects = set(obj for obj in bpy.data.objects)

# ensure we are in object mode
if bpy.context.active_object.mode != 'OBJECT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)

# clear object selection so the context is correct
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    
for obj in objects:    
    if obj.type != 'MESH':
        print(f"Skipping {obj.name} of type {obj.type}")
        continue
    
    print(f"Checking materials of {obj.name} ")

    # select object, switch to edit mode & clear vertex selection
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    
    # check material slots
    found = 0
    for idx, slot in enumerate(obj.material_slots):
        if "screen" in slot.material.name:              #  <-- materials to look for
            print(f"Found material slot #{idx}: {slot.name}")
            # select the material slot, then select all vertices with this material
            bpy.context.object.active_material_index = idx
            bpy.ops.object.material_slot_select()
            found += 1

    # do 'Separate Selection' if we have a selection from at least one match
    if found > 0:
        bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED')

    # switch back to object mode 
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Example output for materials with "Blue" in their name:

```
Checking materials of Cube
Found material slot #1: Ocean Blue
Found material slot #2: Deep Blue
Found material slot #3: Blue Sky
Checking materials of Cylinder
Skipping Camera of type CAMERA
Skipping Light of type LIGHT
Checking materials of Cube default
Checking materials of Sphere
Found material slot #1: Night Blue Sphere
```

Comment: thank you a lot bro, that is exactly what I was searching but couldn`t find in forums and Blender API documentations. Thank you

Comment: Hello everybody!
May I ask you about the script from Blunder?
I've tried this script in Blender 3.6 but it leaves me with this error:

  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.6\3.6\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Nothing selected

Allthough with print statement I verified in the console, that the correct slot was found:
Checking materials of Plane 
Found material slot #1: metal_ornaments_29_55
> Mark as Asset

I am trying to to mark the active material slot as an asset! Thx! :-)

Comment: Hi there. The "ops.py" is a Blender internal script. I guess the error is more likely in your script ;-) It looks like there is something not selected as expected. It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your script. Feel free to post a new question, show your script - or even better an example that causes the error, the full error message including the calls and line numbers, and link this question here so we know what you have done.